# How to deserialize objects stored with a different Java version?

Tags: java, serialization

I work on a quite big Java project (a simulation program) which is under ongoing development, but parallely running in different versions on different computers.

At runtime, the current simulation state can be saved as an object stream to be continued later, possibly on a different computer - this is a quite crucial feature. As the current available version of the program might not be compatible with the old version which serialized a stream some time ago, I store the whole program in a JAR file together with the stored stream to be able to cleanly deserialize it with the program version which created it.

However, I now noticed that the Java version itself is also a pitfall (obviously) meaning that the same Java version has to run on the deserializing system which was used to serialize the stream. To make things worse, even different updates of Java 8 appear to be incompatible with each other (although I cannot recreate this specific situation anymore as, for now, all computers have the newest update installed). As I cannot control all the Java versions on all the computers the program runs on, this is a serious problem.

I am not very good with serialization, so probably (hopefully) there is a good way to handle this situation which I am just not getting...?

Comment: Have you specified the `serialVersionUID` for your classes?

Comment: Yes. But how can I use it to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you're serializing if different Java 8 updates cause a conflict (the classes don't change that often). It sounds highly dubious. Even so, Serialization was never intended for long time storage, so ditch that and use another data saving scheme.

Comment: Yeah, certainly this is my backup plan. The good thing about serialization is though that users dont have to implement anything to make it work. My program is typically used by students who are no programming experts and just want to implement some simple basic classes. Any suggestions how to keep it preferably simple?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.getProperty("java.version")` to get a string representing the java version you currently run on. Then use it as a key to decide which objects to deserialize.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - I have to deserialize the whole thing.